# "Conflicting models in application..." with external database tables

Tags: django, models

I have an project with a number of applications that accesses both my local MySQL database with 100s of tables, and also several external MySQL and Ms-SQL Server databases with many more tables.  All of the external tables are defined in models using the "managed=False" meta data.

I recently upgraded Django from 1.6 to 1.7 following the instructions in the release notes and other hints, etc. from StackOveflow.

Everything seems to be working again with the exception of all of my applications that access the remote database tables.  Here is an example message:

```
RuntimeError: Conflicting 'bugview_deferred_description_disposition_divisioaf59cb28117de5eb6ddfea0476dab601' models in application 'nvbugsdw': <class 'bug_metrics.models_bugs.BugView_Deferred_Description_Disposition_Divisioaf59cb28117de5eb6ddfea0476dab601'> and <class 'bug_metrics.models_bugs.BugView_Deferred_Description_Disposition_Divisioaf59cb28117de5eb6ddfea0476dab601'>.
```

The table BugView is defined in a file names models_bugs.py as follows:

```
class BugView(models.Model):
BugId            = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
Module           = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False)
Requester        = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False)
QAEngineer       = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False)
Engineer         = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False)
RequestDate      = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
ModifiedDate     = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
Priority         = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
Severity         = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
Disposition      = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False)
BugAction        = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False)
Origin           = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False)
GeographicOrigin = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False)
Division         = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False)
Synopsis         = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)
Description      = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=False)
BugType          = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
OriginalBugId    = models.BigIntegerField()

class Meta:
    app_label = 'nvbugsdw'
    managed   = False
    db_table  = 'bugview'
```

In the views.py file the class is imported like:

```
from .models_bugs import BugView
```

I also tried

```
from models_bugs import BugView
from bug_metrics.models_bugs import BugView
```

"bug_metrics" is the application name.

I followed all of the suggestions previously posted on https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22280 to no effect.

I'm at a loss at this point.  Any suggestions?

Also, this may not be related, but in trying to debug this issue (by dumping sys.path in manage.py), I noticed that the code in manage.py is executed twice when I run the command

```
./manage.py runserver --nothreading 0.0.0.0:8081
```

My sys.path is:

```
/opt/graphic_tools/gtools
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/South-0.8.4-py2.7.egg
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol
```

"/opt/graphic_tools/gtools" is my project directory.  It does NOT contain a **init**.py file and does contain all of the application sub-directories  including a "gtools" sub-directory.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion. Did you try to synchronize your 'remote' databases after upgrading to the new version of Django? Maybe they are not synced?

I assume you have something like:
DATABASES = {

'default': {some credentials},

'remote_db_name1': {some credentials},

'remote_db_name2': {some credentials},
...

}

you can run

> ./manage.py migrate --database=remote_db_name1
>
> ./manage.py migrate --database=remote_db_name2

etc.
(Also, I assume you ran 'makemigrations' for your app before.)

The reason is that by default migrate operates on 'default' db, so the others could be skipped.

Comment: I did run migrate on the local databases.

Comment: I did not on the remote ones since they are remote and not managed by Django.

Comment: When I run

./manage.py migrate --database=<remote database 1>

I get

Comment: 'NotImplementedError: subclasses of BaseDatabaseWrapper may require a schema_editor() method'

which seems like I now have this issue:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72542?

Comment: Ok, Figured out how to fix it.  And this is going to sound really stupid.

I upgrade from 1.6 to 1.7 by running:

    sudo pip install django 1.7

Which loaded Django 1.7.0.  When I actually used:

    sudo pip install django=="1.7.11"

1.7.11 was instaled and the problem went away.

So the problem must have been addressed in a release between 1.7.0 and 1.7.11.

This was figured out over here: https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/issues/52

Comment: Nice! I am glad that a simple solution was found. So, we actually dealt with a bug that was removed in version 1.7.11.

Answer (score 0):

So, in my particular case, the problem was caused by running an older version of Django.  I thought I installed 1.7.11 but actually installed 1.7.0.  When I installed 1.7.11 the problem went away.

Wrong way:

```
sudo pip install django=="1.7"
```

Correct way:

```
sudo pip install django=="1.7.11"
```